# apache2handler Keepalive is still on even though I turned it off in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos7

We're running centos 7, lamp stack 5.6 we send 17k sms per day among other things, like streaming, so the server is always busy. Some users complain about not receiving the SMS, the SMS gateway says it's because of a curl timeout, so I did many things  to try and solve it, amongst the stuff i did is turning off `keepalive` in `httpd.conf`

But it still shows under apache2handler in php.ini

```
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: off - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 60 - Keep-Alive: 5
```

Ideally, I'd like to remove apache2handler altogether because this is a production server with at least 30k users per day and I don't like running stuff I don't fully understand on a production server, apache2handler apparently got installed by mistake the other day when upgrading from centos 6.

If the remove of apache2handler may cause downtime, I want to know to get rid of, or increase `Connection: 60 - Keep-Alive: 5`

Answer (score 0):

Turning off php's apachehandler in a lamp stack? You may as well switch off that system. Don't worry about a keepalive timeout of 5 seconds when the keepalive is switched off.

Comment: I don't remember seeing apache2handler before, seems some kind of fastcgi alternative that got installed by mistake